# Json to string to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

i have a json string returned to a hidden value and i want to assign it to a javascript array and print each element of the array.

Json string returned by hdn_client_windows - ["5703","5704"]

Javascript array assignment is as below.

```
var times = $('#hdn_client_windows').val();
alert(times[0]); // this printed only--> [
alert(times[1]); // this printed only--> "
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: As you said, it returns a JSON *string* - not an array object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON into an array with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) first:

```
var times = JSON.parse($('#hdn_client_windows').val());
```

Since you are already using jQuery, it might be a good idea to defer to `$.parseJSON` instead just to be on the safe side (full compatibility with old browsers):

```
var times = $.parseJSON($('#hdn_client_windows').val());
```

Comment: @Jon, Just added the link for the one who is not using jQuery. Direct link to JSON js library :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to parse the string first using JSON.parse (older browsers might require you to load this in):

```
var times = JSON.parse($('#hdn_client_windows').val());
alert(times[0]); // Will display first item
alert(times[1]); // Will display second item
```

Comment: Please fix/remove the comments from the code you've copied. There are few things that are worse than a misleading/wrong comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

```
var str = '["5703","5704"]';
var times = $.parseJSON( str );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use jquery's `parseJSON()` function.

```
var str = '["5703","5704"]';
var parsed = $.parseJSON( str );
```

The `parsed` object now contains the array: `["5703","5704"]`

> Reference - [`jQuery.parseJSON( json )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)
>
> "Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object."